# Unable to Open Excel file from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am able to open an Excel file if I receive email having subject line: Run CIRM Dashboard.

When I receive email with subject line: "Run Dashboard", the Excel file does not open. There is no error.

I require more files to be opened based on the Outlook subject line.

---

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olNameSpace     As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Folder          As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Items = Folder.Items
End Sub


Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        If InStr(Item.Subject, "Run CIRM Dashboard") Then

            Call CIRMDashboard
        If InStr(Item.Subject, "Run Dashboard") Then

        Call PendingForRefund

        End If

        End If

    End If   
End Sub


Public Function CIRMDashboard()
Dim xlapp As Object
Dim sourceWB
Dim sourceWS

Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlapp
    .Visible = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

strFile = "C:\Users\Dharmendra\Desktop\CIRM Dashboard Auto_Runner.xlsm" '\\ my fist file path
Set sourceWB = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(strFile) ', , False, , , , , , , True)

End Function


Public Function PendingForRefund()
Dim xlapp As Object
Dim sourceWB
Dim sourceWS

Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlapp
    .Visible = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

strFile = "C:\Users\Dharmendra\Desktop\CRM Dashboard Auto_Runner.xlsm" ' \\my second file path
Set sourceWB = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(strFile) ', , False, , , , , , , True)

End Function
```

Comment: Try Else after `Call CIRMDashboard`  [If...Then ....Else](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `If` construct ... proper indentation will help visualizing what really happens ...

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        If InStr(Item.Subject, "Run CIRM Dashboard") Then

            Call CIRMDashboard

            If InStr(Item.Subject, "Run Dashboard") Then

                Call PendingForRefund

            End If

        End If

    End If   

End Sub
```

The "Run Dashboard" `If` runs **inside** the "Run CIRM" Dashboard" `If`... so you will never hit this condition (unless a mail with subject "*run CIRM dashboard and then run dashboard*" or the likes is received.

You probably want to replace the 2nd `If` by an `Else If` to bring it to the same level